# Correct format of a UNC path for CACLS for a remote folder

Tags: windows, shared, cacls

I would like to list the ACLs on a file that is shared on a remote machine (I do have all the admin permissions)

It is available in \win2003ad\testfolder

When I run the command

```
cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder
```

I get the error "The network path could not be found." However, when I point out to a particular object in the shared folder, e.g.

```
cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder\users.csv
```

I get the correct result. Also, I get the correct result when I check it locally, i.e.

```
cacls c:\testfolder
```

Have you got any idea how this can be solved? (I can only use command line (no PS) and I run win2003

Comment: Try `cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder\.`

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this doesn't work as well...

Comment: How about `cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder\` ?  Or `cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder\otherfolder\..` where `otherfolder` exists?  If these don't work either it may not be possible without using `psexec` or a similar tool to run the command on the server itself.  (I believe there is a remote command tool built into Windows, but as I always use `psexec` I don't recall its name offhand.)

Comment: cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder` also doesn't work - having another folder (and file) works fine though. So, apparently the top level folder can't be queried...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite old now, but no solution yet... cacls is an old tool, you should use icacls:

```
icacls \\win2003ad\testfolder
```

Just tried it on a Windows Server 2003, just in case the command was not there yet, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this yesterday

```
cacls \\win2003ad\testfolder\*
```

Comment: That lists the permissions on the files and subfolders, but not the permissions on the folder itself.  Not on my machine, at any rate.